# Bind Treeview inside Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, repeater

I want to bind the Tree view inside the repeater like below image:

[image]

please tell me the way how can I do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
protected void myRepeater_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        TreeView MyTree = (TreeView)e.Item.FindControl("MyTreeID");
        MyTree.DataSource = MyDataSoure;
        MyTree.DataBind();
    }
}
```